# IO + subprocess.check_output iteration breaking file writes

Tags: python, io, subprocess

I am writing a python script that will go through a code file, comment out an import, build the program, and determine if each import is actually being used.

I have each component working, but for some reason when I combine them I am getting a very weird issue while writing back to the code file. It seems like whenever I use subprocess.check_output for building the code, the write commands for the file seem to always stop writing around line 315 without continuing on in the file. I would assume it was some race condition but it will always end on the same line each time I run it.

I have also tried with os.system() and had the same results. I'm not much of a python coder so maybe there is something obvious with IO that I'm missing?

**Some Code:**

```
with open(file, 'r+') as f:
        content = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()

        lines = re.split("\r?\n", content);

        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            result = regex.search(line)

            if (result):
                commentLine = '//' + line + ' //Not Needed'

                lines[index] = commentLine

                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                for writeLine in lines:
                    f.write("%s\n" % writeLine)

                returnValue = 0;

                try:
                    returnValue = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/xcodebuild', '-workspace', 'path_to_my_workspace' ,'-configuration', 'Debug', '-scheme', 'my_scheme'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
                except:
                    returnValue = 1

                if (returnValue == 0): #Build succeeded!
                    print "Build succeeded!"
                else:#Build failed
                    print "Build failed"

                    lines[index] = line
                    f.seek(0)
                    f.truncate()
                    for writeLine in lines:
                        f.write("%s\n" % writeLine)
```

**Walkthrough:**
Opens a file,
Splits it line by line searching for a regex matching #import etc etc,
Comments out this line,
Tries to build it,
If success, leave the comment,
if fail, remove the comment,
repeat for each regex match